# Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{e^{2t} +1}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(t) = \frac{1}{e^{2t} + 1}.
\end{align}
Is it possible to evaluate the Laplace transform $L\lbrace f(t) \rbrace$ ?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{z-1}dx}{1+x}=\pi\csc(z\pi)$ for $\Re z\in(0,\,1)$?

Comment: It's the first time for me to see such a formula. @J.G.

Comment: In that case, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).